# Windows keyboard on mac, change combinations?

Tags: keyboard

I have my reasons why I use a Win keyboard on a Mac, I'm interested to know how can I change keyboard combinations like: change  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  vs.  <kbd>Win</kbd>  key, I want on Mac to have  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  functionality on  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  key and  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  on  <kbd>Win</kbd> ... it is possible or does any software exist for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change Modifier Key Assignment from
System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard > Modifier Keys...

[image]

Comment: Thank you, is there any default possibility to setup all combinations like on windows? I mean window switch, tab switch in browsers etc...?

Comment: Not natively. BetterTouchTool & Karabiner are capable of that sort of tweak - but honestly, you'd be far better off in the long run just learning the difference.